# Possible to order by certain words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sql-order-by

I have a `Project` model with the attribute `status`.

`status` can be saved to one of the following values: `Ongoing`, `Completed`, `Scheduled`.

**Is it possible to order records such that those with the `status` value of `Scheduled` comes first, `Ongoing` second and `Completed` last?**

A second order clause will order the projects chronologically within each status segment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return records ordered by `status` column, as you required:

```
Project.order('case projects.status
  when 'Scheduled' then 0
  when 'Ongoing' then 1
  when 'Completed' then 2
end')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `order` with a custom expression:

```
CASE status
  WHEN 'Ongoing' THEN 3
  WHEN 'Completed' THEN 2
  WHEN 'Scheduled' THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the `where` method. Something to the effect of:

```
Project.all.order('updated_at').group('status')
```

Just be careful because group returned a hash, so it might not function exactly as you expect. The documentation can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group).